# Simpler solution to MYSQL statements and building PHP associative array out of My data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the first time a patient diagnosed with the cancer, cancer name and type.
I have managed to retrieve them, but I am sure that there must be an easier way to do it.

```
$id = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("SELECT diagnosis_id from ddpt where patientnhs_no = '$nhsno' order by diagnosis_id asc limit 1")))[0];

    //get the date of the first diagnosis using the diagnosis id 
    $date = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("select date from diagnosis where diagnosis_id ='$id'")))[0];

    //get the id of the cancer name
    $ctype_id = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("select ctype_id from diagnosis where diagnosis_id ='$id'")))[0];

    //get the id of the histology name
    $hname_id = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("select hname_id from diagnosis where diagnosis_id ='$id'")))[0];

    //get the name of the cancer type
    $cname = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("select name from cancertype where ctype_id ='$ctype_id'")))[0];

    //get the name of the histology 
    $ctype = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("select hist_name from histologynames where hname_id ='$hname_id'")))[0];
```

Comment: There probably is an easier way, but this is much too broad a request. Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may select multiple columns in one query and even use `join`:

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT diagnosis_id, date, ctype_id, hname_id, name, hist_name
               FROM ddpt
               JOIN diagnosis ON diagnosis.diagnosis_id = ddpt.diagnosis_id
               JOIN cancertype ON cancertype.ctype_id = diagnosis.ctype_id
               JOIN histologynames ON histologynames.hname_id = diagnosis.hname_id
               WHERE patientnhs_no = '$nhsno'
               ORDER BY ddpt.diagnosis_id ASC LIMIT 1");

$result = array_values(mysqli_fetch_array($query));
```

the code itself needs optimizing, but for the basic usage it's okay.

Comment: @Nurettin don't forget to mark as answered in case other users come up with such a problem

Answer (score 0):

get everything that your need in one statement by joining tables in your query,

```
"select column1,column2,column3... from table1,table2,table3";
```

Then loop through using foreach and if statements.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 items from the table diagnosis can be done in 1 query. The basics of this idea will be like:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT date, ctype_id, hname_id 
    FROM diagnosis 
    WHERE diagnosis_id ='$id
'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
$date = $row["date"];
$ctype_id = $row["ctype_id"];
$hname_id = $row["hname_id"];
```